# Pass an href ID to a Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, popup

I have a page which has some href elements with unique IDs. When I click the link, it will open a pop-up page with a form. I need to pass the href's ID to the form(as hidden input). How can I pass the href's ID to the pop-up form.

Both href and pop-up form are in separate pages.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart overlayLink" id="book6"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
```

This is the href in my home page. There is a Jquery to open the form. When the form is submitted, I need this href's Id also to pass with the form details.

Comment: Hidden fields can be added by passing an associative array to the third parameter, like this:

$hidden = array('username' => 'Joe', 'member_id' => '234');

echo form_open('email/send', '', $hidden);

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

USE FORM POST if you want to keep things hidden:

```
$data["id"] = ("ID NUMBER");
$this->load->view("VIEW ", $data);
```

ANCHOR IN VIEW

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/controllerB/controllerfunction/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="See more" />
</form>
```

You could also use javascript to submit the form here via link if you which:

```
<a href="javascript;" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();"> See more</a>
Tips:You could also use css to hide submit button in the form by setting opacity to 0; If link is within the form, you could use javascript:this.submit();
OR JQUERY

<a href="javascript;" id="link">See more</a>
$('#link').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
$id = $this->input->post("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will work:**

```
 <a onclick="javascript:document.myform.submit();" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart overlayLink" id="book6"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>

    <form name="myform" id="myform" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/controllerB/controllerfunction/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="book6" value="book6" />
    </form>
```